# How to insert buttons into textbox for filename template editor

Tags: c#, button, textbox, filenames

I have a c# winform and I want to create a "File Name Template Form" for users like Adobe Photoshop Lightroom's (below picture and video). How can I design textbox like Lightroom's ones?

I'm not sure that the UI input element is called. It looks a bit like a [pills/tags/chips input](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/98069/163248) except each item is also a dropdown. I'm not sure what the secret is to this design, but maybe they used a few elements.

[image]

https://youtu.be/oJHfZtrYEbo?t=246

I tried it with tokenEdit toolbox of devexpress but it does not meet my demands.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. With the built-in textbox control, this is not possible (as far as I know). If you want to use this exact format, you are sadly forced to create your own control that has this feature as a possibility.

What id suggest as a quick solution is to have a normal textbox, but then you can type in special text that can be interpreted via string manipulation to give you what you want.

example:

```
string fileName = "image - [num] [date] [time].jpg"
```

gets translated like this:

```
public void TranslateText(ref string text)
{
    text.Replace("[num]", i.ToString());
    text.Replace("[date]", DateTime.Now.Date);
    text.Replace("[time]", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
}
TranslateText(fileName);
```

Comment: Victor, thanks for your response. It is a good solution, but I currently use regular expressions in a similar way. Just trying to make a design that are more user-friendly.